# large columns sum for each row in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table like this:

```
ID  var_1  var_2 Var_3 .....Var_n
 1   1       1      2         3 
 2   4       5      6         8
 3   2       5      5         5
```

i tried

```
Select *, sum(week_1_week_2+…+week_n)/n.0 from table group by ID;
```

is there any fast way to do it ??

Comment: what do you mean by "fast way"?....a way without listing every column?

Comment: if n=100 ,  is there any way that i don't have to type sum(var_1+var_2+...+var100)?

Comment: just dynamic SQL, or list every column of the table using a system table/view. But you aren't really saving much time

Comment: Two approaches.  1) use system tables to dynamically identify all columns needed and generate the SQL dynamically. 2) unpivot the data and then sum.

Comment: if i want to unpivot the table and sum , is there any way to do it ?? (sorry i'm really new to this

Answer (score 1):

The `sum()` and `group by` do not seem appropriate:

```
Select t.*, (week_1_week_2+…+week_n)/n.0
from table t;
```